# How to get text input continuously in Unity C#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm going to get text input using `TextField` and the following is my code:

```
public Text textInput;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)) {
        if (textInput.text == "go") {
            /* do something */
            textInput.text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I assigned the `Text` element under `TextField` to `public Text textInput`, and I expected that once a player types "go" and presses enter, the `TextField` will be cleared and the player be able to type next sentence.
However, after I type "go" and press enter, the text in `TextField` remained and the focus was out.
How can I clear the `TextField` maintaining the focus on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "problem" is that the input field by default also handles the <kbd>Return</kbd> key as the submission command which automatically loses the focus.

The default [`InputField.lineType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-lineType.html) is

[`SingleLine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.LineType.SingleLine.html)

> Only allows 1 line to be entered. Has horizontal scrolling and no word wrap. Pressing enter will submit the InputField.

You could instead set it to [`MultiLineNewLine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.LineType.MultiLineNewline.html)

> Is a multiline InputField with vertical scrolling and overflow. Pressing the return key will insert a new line character.

So it doesn't automatically call the `OnSubmit` and lose focus when pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

---

Using that as an alternative to use `Update` and `GetKeyDown` you could use [`InputField.onValidateInput`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValidateInput.html) and do something like

```
public InputField textInput;

private void Awake ()
{
    textInput.lineType = InputField.LineType.MultiLineNewLine;
    textInput.onValidateInput = OnValidate;
}

private char OnValidate(string text, int charIndex, char addedChar)
{
    if(addedChar == '\n')
    {
        if(text.Equals("go"))
        {
            // Do something
        }

        textInput.text = "";
        return '';
    }

    return addedChar;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Probably `textInput` had to be an `InputField` object.

Comment: @dbld oh yes of course :'D didn't even note that it was not before ^^